# Как растянуть дочерний div на всю ширину bootstrap4

Tags: bootstrap4

Нужно растянуть на всю ширину по предыдущему div вот этот

```
<div class="bg-white border rounded px-2 py-2 my-2 text-center">
```

подскажите как это можно сделать с помощью bootstrap?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
<br>
<main role="main" class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-auto bg-dark ">
      <div class="bg-white border rounded px-2 py-2 my-2 text-center">
        <img src="https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/profile-icon-male-avatar-portrait-casual-person-silhouette-face-flat-design-vector-illustration-58249394.jpg" width="200px">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: Это весь код? Просто .row немыслимо без .container или .container-fluid.

Comment: @Quazimorda он есть добавил в код

Comment: Так div class="bg-white..." занимает всю ширину. Картинка в нём 200 пикселей. Что не так-то?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="row justify-content-center">
  <div class="col-3 pl-0 pr-0 bg-dark">
    <div class="bg-white border rounded px-2 py-2 my-2 text-center">
      <img src="https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/profile-icon-male-avatar-portrait-casual-person-silhouette-face-flat-design-vector-illustration-58249394.jpg" width="150px">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-7 bg-white border rounded p-3 my-2">
    <table class="table table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">#</th>
          <th scope="col">First</th>
          <th scope="col">Last</th>
          <th scope="col">Handle</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">1</th>
          <td>Mark</td>
          <td>Otto</td>
          <td>@mdo</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">2</th>
          <td>Jacob</td>
          <td>Thornton</td>
          <td>@fat</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">3</th>
          <td>Larry</td>
          <td>the Bird</td>
          <td>@twitter</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```